# How to target Windows Universal Apps to work only on Windows phone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

Hi guys I was wondering if there is a way to make a Windows Universal Application but then restrict it to only work on Windows phone. If it is possible can you guys link me or tell me how its done?

Comment: When you submit the app to the store you can choose devices which it supports and there you can limit it only to mobile.

Comment: Please check the official document [TargetDeviceFamily (Windows 10)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt617332.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the Package.appxmanifest file and change the TargetDeviceFamily from "Windows.Universal" to "Windows.Mobile".

You can't do this through the manifest editor, so you will have to edit file manually.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Roger Hartley's perfectly good answer, find the bit that looks like this:

```
<Dependencies>
  <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
```

...and change it to this:

```
<Dependencies>
  <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
```